# Unable to work with emulator, using react-native and expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am using react native with expo, OS: Elementary OS, Emulator: Android Studio emulator.

getting the following error when trying to open the app in emulator

```
12:58:16: Starting Android...
Error running adb: Error running app. Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=exp://192.168.0.101:19000 flg=0x10000000 }


 › Press a to open Android device or emulator, or i to open iOS emulator.
 › Press q to display QR code.
 › Press r to restart packager, or R to restart packager and clear cache.
 › Press d to toggle development mode. (current mode: development)

(node:15266) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at /xdl/src/Android.js:90:18
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/home/afzal/AFZAL/Cloud_Drive/Development/React Native/react-native-boilerplate-redux-flow-master/node_modules/xdl/build/Android.js:475:191)
    at /home/afzal/AFZAL/Cloud_Drive/Development/React Native/react-native-boilerplate-redux-flow-master/node_modules/xdl/build/Android.js:475:361
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
(node:15266) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Download XDE of expo and create project from XDE

https://github.com/expo/xde/releases

run app through same wifi connection in your pc and mobile or you can connect with data cable

for Emulator start the Emulator first and then run the app 
you can use genymotion for Emulator